# Create a vector in a dataframe based on matching a second vector to a row name in another object

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame:

```
group <- c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b')
x<- c(1.1,2.3,1.9,3.5,11.1,12.3,11.9,13.5)
y<- c(1,2.1,2.1,3.6,1.2,2.2,1.8,3.4)
d<- data.frame(group,x,y)

d  
group    x   y
1     a  1.1 1.0
2     a  2.3 2.1
3     a  1.9 2.1
4     a  3.5 3.6
5     b 11.1 1.2
6     b 12.3 2.2
7     b 11.9 1.8
8     b 13.5 3.4
```

I then fit a mixed effects model using `lme` and save the coefficients as an output table.

```
require(nlme)
m1<- lme(x~y,random=~1|group,data=d)
m1.out<- coef(m1)

m1.out
  (Intercept)         y
a  0.02631376 0.9883314
b 10.07444484 0.9883314
```

Now, based on this output, I would like to create a new vector in `d` that is the intercept values stored in `m1.out`. The answer must be able to generalize, as this is a simplification of a problem with many more levels of the random effect. Ideally the output would look like this:

```
  group    x   y   intercept
1     a  1.1 1.0  0.02631376
2     a  2.3 2.1  0.02631376
3     a  1.9 2.1  0.02631376
4     a  3.5 3.6  0.02631376
5     b 11.1 1.2 10.07444484
6     b 12.3 2.2 10.07444484
7     b 11.9 1.8 10.07444484
8     b 13.5 3.4 10.07444484
```

Comment: Try `d$intercept <- m1.out[match(d$group, rownames(m1.out)), 1]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg winner!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest two options

Either you can use base `match` function as in

```
d$intercept <- m1.out[match(d$group, rownames(m1.out)), 1]
```

---

Or a more generals solution would be to merge the two data sites. I'd suggest using `data.table` for both speed and concise code.

First we will convert to a `data.table` object while coercing the row names to a new column `rn` and fixing the invalid column name - all in one `setDT` call. Then we will perform a simple binary join while using the new `on` argument

```
library(data.table) #v1.9.6+
setDT(m1.out, keep.rownames = TRUE, check.names = TRUE) 
setDT(d)[m1.out, intercept := i.X.Intercept., on = c(group = "rn")]
d
#    group    x   y   intercept
# 1:     a  1.1 1.0  0.02631376
# 2:     a  2.3 2.1  0.02631376
# 3:     a  1.9 2.1  0.02631376
# 4:     a  3.5 3.6  0.02631376
# 5:     b 11.1 1.2 10.07444484
# 6:     b 12.3 2.2 10.07444484
# 7:     b 11.9 1.8 10.07444484
# 8:     b 13.5 3.4 10.07444484
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using **dplyr** and **broom**.

```
library(broom)
library(dplyr)

intercepts <- m1 %>%
    tidy() %>%
    filter(term == '(Intercept)') %>%
    rename(intercept=estimate) %>%
    select(level, intercept)

d %>% left_join(intercepts, by=c(group='level'))

#   group    x   y intercept
# 1     a  1.1 1.0   0.02631
# 2     a  2.3 2.1   0.02631
# 3     a  1.9 2.1   0.02631
# 4     a  3.5 3.6   0.02631
# 5     b 11.1 1.2  10.07444
# 6     b 12.3 2.2  10.07444
# 7     b 11.9 1.8  10.07444
# 8     b 13.5 3.4  10.07444
```

Comment: This is good, but I think @davidarenburg had the best solution in his comment: `d$intercept <- m1.out[match(d$group, rownames(m1.out)), 1]`

Comment: This isn't as concise as @DavidArenburg's answer. You would choose an answer like this one to maximize readability.